# TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert CSV data into an Oracle table. But getting error as

> TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as srcfile:
reader = csv.reader(srcfile, dialect = 'fileProperties')
header = next(reader)
header = ", ".join(str(h) for h in header)
insert = 'insert into table (' + header + ') values ('
#print(insert) 

for row in reader:
    data = [insert + str(row).strip("[]") + ');']

cur.prepare(data)
cur.execute(data)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-8814eee5c788> in <module>
  1 #cur.prepare(data)
----> 2 cur.execute(data)

TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

How can I fix the code?

Comment: `data` is a list.  I don't believe you can pass a list as the argument to `prepare()` or `execute()`.

Comment: have removed list and tried, getting error as ORA-00911: invalid character. But i took the print statement of the data and inserted in the database and its working

Comment: If the error & issue is not the same anymore, you should either re-write the question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved the issue.

- First issue is, list cannot be passed as a parameter while using executemany, but list 
  works while using execute
- Second issue is, need to bind the source data while inserting. However instead of hard 
  coding the binding variables, got the column names and passed the bind variables 
  dynamically, so that any column added or removed in the file can be handled without 
  modifying the code

  ```
  with open('G:\Project\ETL\data\CME.csv', 'r') as srcfile:
  reader = csv.reader(srcfile, dialect = 'fileProperties')
  header = next(reader)
  columns = ", ".join(str(h) for h in header)
  length = len(next(reader))
  bind = []
  data = []

  for binds in range(1, length+1):
      bind.append(':' + str(binds))


  insert = 'insert into ledger_source_python (' + columns + ') values (' + ", ".join(str(l) for l in bind) + ')' 

  for row in reader:
      data.append(row)

  cur.executemany(insert, data)
  con.commit()
  ```